# Why would an observable array have 0 length on my template, but not in my JS in knockout.js?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm having some trouble with conditional rendering in knockout.js. I have an `observableArray` in my view model, which is created using `ko.utils.arrayMap()`. In my javascript code, outputting the length of that array returns the expected length. However, when I try to output that same length in my view, it's always 0.

Here is my view code:

```html
<!-- ko if: people().length == 0 -->
    <p data-bind="text: people().length"></p>
    <!-- always outputs 0 -->
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: people().length > 0 -->
    <p data-bind="text: people().length"></p>
    <!-- never reaches this -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Javascript:

```
var data = [
    {
        firstName: "Bob",
        lastName: "Smith"
    },
    {
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "Doe"
    },
    {
        firstName: "Jane",
        lastName: "Doe"
    }
];

function Person(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

function ViewModel(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.people = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function(i) {
        return ko.observable(new Person(i.firstName, i.lastName));
    }));
    console.log(self.people().length);  //Outputs 3, as expected
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(data));
```

Comment: Your code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/64wbN/1/...

Comment: Whaaat? Maybe it's a problem somewhere else. In my actual code, data comes from the server as json, and my observable array is properly populated. console.log(people().length) outputs 7, but in the view it outputs 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can happen if you replace an observable in the view model instead of assigning to it. You might have `self.people = ko.observableArray();` in your view model constructor. Later, when you actually get the data, you have `self.people = ko.observableArray(thedata);`.

In this case, your view model knows about the data, but the view was bound to the earlier observable and doesn't know about the later one. Instead you should have `self.people(thedata);` to set the data.